# Send dynamic HTML list with PHP to server

Tags: php, jquery, html

I have two simple HTML lists. The first one contains a bunch of entries, the second one is initially empty. The common list structure is the following:

```
<ul id="project-offer-list" class="connectedSortable">
    <li class="ui-state-default">
        <div>
            <!-- formatting -->
        </div>
    </li>
    <li class="ui-state-default">
        <div>
            <!-- formatting -->
        </div>
```

The user can select some entries from the first list by dragging them to the second one. By doing so he can give a preference by sorting the elements within the second list.

The drag-drop-mechanism is realized by JQuery:

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $("#project-offer-list, #project-selection-list").sortable({
            connectWith: ".connectedSortable"
        }).disableSelection();
    });
</script>
```

I want to send both the selected elements (those in the second list) and their order to a remote server with PHP. Whenever the user clicks the "Save" button, the current selection should be sent.

How can I achieve this? I would need to assign an id to each list element and somehow read the second list and its order. It is crucial that possible changes in the HTML code made by JQuery are considered.

Thanks

Comment: Add one hidden field, add form tags to hold it. When user moves and orders elements Javascript should create and update an array of element IDs in particular order, and assign it to the hidden field. You can send the value of hidden field to server using ajax. I think the value should be formatted as json.

Comment: You haven't shown you you uniquely identify the elements being sorted such that you can distinguish what data needs to be sent to the backend.

Answer (score 1):

You Need to convert the data of the second list into json object, assign the id to each element, use the same id which you have in your database as it would be more easy to update and perform options on existing data,

```
    var items = [];
    $('ul#list_id').find("li").each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    var item = { id: $(this).attr('data-id'), title: $(this).text() };
    items.push(item);
  });
```

You will get something like this, and use an ajax to send this to your remote server

```
[
 {"id":"1","title":"School-management"}, 
 {"id":"2","title":"library-management"}, 
 {"id":"3","title":"billing_software"}
]
```